# Resume repo sync after receiving 100% objects

Tags: android, synchronization, ubuntu-10.10, repository

i was downloading the latest gingerbread source, after receiving all the objects(appx 242) in .Repo folder, it was writing files on the HDD, when i ran out of Hard disk space, is there any way to resume the sync, it took me approx 4 hours to sync 3 GB of data.

Comment: there is no answer to my question :)

Answer (score 1):

Usually you can just do another `repo sync` and it will continue from where it left off. Does that not work for you?

Comment: No that didn't work for me, i guess it again downloaded > 3GB data.

Comment: Sounds wrong. How far in the process was it. Did it create any files outside of the `.repo/` folder yet?

Comment: Hmmm. cant remember that, but i am sure the download was 100% and moved on to next step.